# Renaming a set of directories according to the number of sub directories each directory contains in ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I want to rename a set of directories according to the number of subdirectories each directory contains.

For example, if "A" directory is containing "B" , "C" , and "D" subdirectories and "B" contains "E" and "F" while "C" contains only "G" and "D" contains only "H".Then "B" should be renamed as "m_B"(m for multiple)."C" and "D" remains the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script.

The first thing you need to do is to count the number of directories of this folders.

```
ls -l $1 | grep ^d | wc -l
```

Then assign this value to a variable:

```
TOTAL=$(ls -1 $1 | grep ^d | wc -l)
```

Now the only thing you need to do is a simple check with an if clause

```
if [ $TOTAL -gt 1 ]
 then
  mv "$1" "m_$1" 
 pwd
fi
```

So the final script for check one folder is:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  TOTAL=$(ls -1 $1 | grep ^d | wc -l)
      if [ $TOTAL -gt 1 ]
     then
      mv "$1" "m_$1" 
     pwd
    fi
```

That script will work for one folder passed by argument, if you want to use this script to rename a set of of folders, use a for clause.

Comment: This script is working fine.nice explanation by the way.but my script should read "B" , "C" and "D" iteratively(using loop is preferable) one by one and rename "B" as "m_B" while "C" and "D" remains the same.

Comment: Its ok, only add another for loop like this:

for file in $( ls -l | grep ^d | cut -d " " -f 9)
do
  TOTAL=$(ls -1 $file | grep ^d | wc -l)
      if [ $TOTAL -gt 1 ]
     then
      mv "$file" "m_$file" 
     pwd
    fi

done